# sed: Replacing a range of text with contents of a file

Tags: bash, replace, sed, insert

There are many examples here and elsewhere on the interwebs for using sed's 'r' to replace a pattern, but it does not seem to work on a range, but maybe I'm just not holding it right.

The following works as expected, deleting BEGIN PATTERN and replacing it with the contents of /tmp/somefile.

```
sed -n "/BEGIN PATTERN/{ r /tmp/somefile d }" TARGET_FILE
```

This, however, only replaces END_PATTERN with the contents of /tmp/somefile.

```
 sed -n "/BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/ { r /tmp/somefile d }" TARGET_FILE
```

I suppose I could try perl or awk to do this as well, but it seems like sed should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
sed  $'/BEGIN PATTERN/r somefile\n /BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/d' file
```

Or:

```
sed  -e '/BEGIN PATTERN/r somefile' -e '/BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/d' file
```

#### How it works

- `/BEGIN PATTERN/r somefile`

  Whenever `BEGIN PATTERN` is found, this inserts the contents of `somefile`.
- `/BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/d`

  Whenever we are in the range from a line with `/BEGIN PATTERN/` to a line with `/END PATTERN/`, we delete (`d`) the contains of the pattern buffer.

#### Example

Let's consider these two test files:

```
$ cat file
prelude
BEGIN PATTERN
middle
END PATTERN
afterthought
```

and:

```
$ cat somefile
This is
New.
```

Our command produces:

```
$ sed  $'/BEGIN PATTERN/r somefile\n /BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/d' file
prelude
This is
New.
afterthought
```

Comment: You might get false positives if the `BEGIN` AND `END` patterns were not paired.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/BEGIN PATTERN/,/END PATTERN/{/END PATTERN/!d;r somefile' -e 'd}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

John1024's answer works if `BEGIN PATTERN` and `END PATTERN` are different. If this is not the case, the following works:

```
sed $'/PATTERN/,/PATTERN/d; 1,/PATTERN/ { /PATTERN/r somefile\n }' file
```

By preserving the pattern:

```
sed $'/PATTERN/,/PATTERN/ { /PATTERN/!d; }; 1,/PATTERN/ { /PATTERN/r somefile\n }' file
```

This solution can yield false positives if the pattern is not paired as potong pointed out.